# Dev c++ does not allow me to allocate much memory

Tags: memory, malloc, dev-c++

I'm using Dev C++ to practice C programming, but while I was executing the program (no problems on compiling) I noticed that depending the data I allocate with malloc the program stops, saying:

> the programm "name".exe stopped working

Any ideas why dev does not allow me to allocate much memory?

Comment: what is "much"? 1 byte, 1 mega byte, 100 gigabytes? does it return NULL? etc

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: also no mention of what OS/platform/bitness